# Positioning of tick labels in a 3D plot

Tags: graphics, ticks

I am looking for an easy way to force this plot to label the $y$ axis with numbers below the axis automatically in the given view point. Now the label switches to the bottom when the view point reaches a certain angle, but I would like to have the labeling always below the $y$-axis.

The existing answers could not help so far (mostly for 2D only). Using the `Epilog` function changes the font and the angle as far as I was able to test it.

Furthermore, I would like to mark the ticks at: `{{0, -20, 0}, {0, -10, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {"r/2", 0, 0}, {"r", 0, 0}}` with a little black cross, but cannot work it out.

Are there ways to solve these problems? Many thanks in advance.

```
circle3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 20, normal_: {0, 0, 1},
angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] :=Composition[Line,
Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre], #] &,
Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &, #] &,
Append[DeleteDuplicates[Most@#], Last@#] &, Level[#, {-2}] &,
MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &, DiscretizeRegion, If][
First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi, Circle[Most@centre, radius],
Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]]

cGr = Graphics3D[{Thick, Dashed, circle3D[{0, 0, 0}, 20]}];
c1 = Graphics3D[{Thick, Dashed, circle3D[{0, 0, 20}, 20]}];

Show[c1,Ticks -> {Automatic,Table[i, {i, -20, 20, 10}], 
Automatic},AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.004], Boxed -> False, Axes -> 
True,AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},Boxed -> False,PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, 
{-20, 20}, {0, 30}}, ImagePadding -> {{0, 40}, {40, 70}},
ViewPoint -> {0.8 Pi, -1.5 Pi, 0.20 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a brute-force method that simply suppresses the tick labels automatically generated, and creates `Graphics3D[Text[...` objects to put where we want them.

```
xticks = Table[
    Text[ToString @ n, {n, 0, -1.5}],
    {n, -20, 20, 10}
];
yticks = Table[Text[ToString @ n, {0, n, -1.5}],
    {n, -20, 20, 10}
];
Show[c1,
    Graphics3D @ {xticks, yticks},
    Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic},
    AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.004],
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, TicksStyle -> {
        Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0],
        Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0],
        Automatic
    },
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {0, 30}},
    ImagePadding -> {{0, 40}, {40, 70}},
    ViewPoint -> {0.8 * Pi, -1.5 * Pi, 0.2 * Pi}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a fine solution.

Comment: The signs of the labels are preserved if you use `ToString` instead of `IntegerString`.

Comment: @Will.Mo thanks for catching that.